# Convert continuous signal of HC-SR501 PIR sensor to a single pulse

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, pir

HC-SR501 PIR sensor sends a continuous signal of 0-3.3V for the period of 4-8 seconds (depending upon the delay set).
Is there a way/IC I can convert this signal to a single pulse of 1 sec, preferably without using a micro-controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 555 Timer in the mono-stable mode which can give you 1 second pulse from your input of 4-8 seconds.

You can refer this datasheet for helping you construct the mono-stable multi-vibrator :

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf